# The package system is broken: I can't update my apps on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Tags: 12.10, apt

screen shot:

[image]

text:

*"Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a terminal: `apt-get install -f`"*

details:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
fgfs-models-base: flightgear: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is installed
        Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
        Depends: libudev0 (>= 147) but 175-0ubuntu13 is installed
        Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13 is installed
```

Comment: Did you try 'sudo apt-get update --fix-missing' and/or 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' (run this commands without quotes in the terminal)?

Comment: yes i did and it did not work

Comment: Did you add a repository in order to install FlightGear? If so, which one?

Comment: no not really not that i remember

Comment: i fix it ok Alex thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try this commands in the Terminal (CTLR+ALT+T):

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If your problem still persists, try downgrading (using Synaptic Package Manager) the packages:

- libc6
- libgcc1
- libstdc++6
- libudev0
- zlib1g

[Tutorial about downgrading packages](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: now i did what you said and this happened. its in order. [link1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30936181/Screenshot%20from%202013-03-10%2014%3A01%3A28.png) [link2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30936181/Screenshot%20from%202013-03-10%2014%3A02%3A10.png) [link3](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30936181/Screenshot%20from%202013-03-10%2014%3A02%3A33.png) [link4](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30936181/Screenshot%20from%202013-03-10%2014%3A04%3A16.png)

Comment: May you post please the text that appeared in the link 4 (to know where and when did the error occur)?